# Copy spreadsheet data to Oracle database

Tags: java, excel, oracle, csv, database-design

I have a spreadsheet with a whole database schema (tables defined with columns, primary keys and indexes). Now I need to import this to an Oracle database. Any pointers to achieve this would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Please read the [help] and also [Why do some questions get closed for no reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49253/why-do-some-questions-get-closed-for-no-reason). This is not a good question for StackOverflow.

Comment: *sigh* Why do people insist on using spreadsheets for everything?

Comment: @APC They are already there on many computers (no effort required to get new software); most people know how to use them (whereas they may have to lean how to use a different software package requiring them to move out of their comfort zone or to invest in training); they are cheap (already there as part of an office suite so no extra license or cost to install/maintain is required). Does not mean they are a good solution but using a spreadsheet does not require much effort to set up an initial solution.

Comment: @MT0 - can you tell me what "rhetorical question" means? ;-)

Comment: @APC - [The OED can](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rhetorical_question). More seriously though, part of the point of me posting was in the hope that it would cause the OP to reflect on the underlying reasons why they are using a spreadsheet (rather than just dismissing your comment as a snarky attack on them) and consider whether they are just using it because it was the "simple" solution that required no inertia to implement or whether, now they are hitting implementation issues, it is the time to invest in a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not a data modelling tool. There is no tool for turning a spreadsheet into an Oracle schema.

You need to convert its contents into DDL statements. The hard way to do this is cut'n'paste. Depending on how the spreadsheet is laid out you may be able to automate the process with regex after converting it into text (Save as tab-delimited or CSV).